# How to connect Raspberry-Pi with laptop Monitor

Tags: raspberry-pi

Is there any way to make my raspberry-pi to be displayed on my laptop monitor? If so please guide the steps to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you do it via a network

- Install tight VNC: `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`
- Start a VNC session `vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x728 -depth 24`
- Install Tight VNC client on your laptop and connect